# Transform.position is keep giving the same value

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public override void Shoot()
{
    if (timeBeforeNextShot != 0) return;

    timeBeforeNextShot = cooldown;

    if (loadedAmmo > 0 && shooter.IsAlive && shooter.activeGun != null)
    {
        Transform camProxy = shooter.transform.Find("CamProxy");
        Vector3 targetPoint = camProxy.position + camProxy.forward.normalized * 50000f;
        Vector3 shootDirection = targetPoint - transform.position;

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camProxy.position, camProxy.forward, out hit))
        {
            targetPoint = hit.point;
            shootDirection = targetPoint - transform.position;
        }

        Projectile.Spawn(shooter, bullet, damage, transform.position, shootDirection * shotSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
        loadedAmmo--;
        base.SendAmmoUpdated();
    }
}
```

this is part of my code that is called when client has clicked left click of fps game that is
based on riptide sample fps project, and I modified it to make gun position more natural ,
and make the projectile starts on  the gun, but for some reason, transform.position keep
returns same value.
the image is the log. as you can see, target gameobject is Gun (which is expected) and the
transform.position is always the same.(which is "not" expected because I was keep moving
during shooting)

the video is ingame clip, as you can see, the starting point of bullet is always same, even
though I am moving around. what is the problem? I got no idea.

the thing I changed from the sample fps project is that I made a Gun object and put it under the original gun objects.

https://github.com/RiptideNetworking/SampleFPS this is the sample fps project.

[image: log]

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1179056927968333884/1179056928559742996/2023-11-28_22-49-16.mp4?ex=65786555&is=6565f055&hm=400352c73ba69b7010a073a9849709a6d246225e8f2723c7c8c438cd755bab74& <- video

Comment: The code never changes `transform.position`.

Comment: should I change it? I thought it will just give me the world location. Then how should I change it?

Comment: Yes it's the world position, it is attached on an object called `Gun`, but is this `Gun` the same thing as the pistol in the video?

Comment: You can use `Debug.Log(gameObject.name, gameObject);`, then click the log, this will tell you exactly which gameObject it is.

Answer (score 0):

The Vector3 `transform.position` refers to the world position of the gameObject to which the script is attached. And this is the position used to shoot the bullet. Make sure your script that contain the `Shoot` function is a component of your gun and that this gun is actually moving in the scene.

Another solution would be to create an empty GameObject named like 'Muzzle' positioned at the exact point where the bullet should be fired, and to reference this gameObject in shoot and then replace `transform.position` by `muzzle.transform.position`.

If the problem still persist, share us the Hierarchy of the scene and the Projectile.Spawn script, maybe the problem is hidden there.

Comment: Um.. all of them didn't work, but some reason it work on new project based on the samplefps project. I got no idea what is wrong, but I think it is solved..?